# I keep getting this error code however cant figure out why ? only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or

Tags: python, numpy

This is my code where p1 and mg1 are arrays of data points. I keep getting the error 'only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices' and tried the other solutions from similar questions but cant seem to get it to work

```
d2=[]

for f,i in zip(p1, mg1):

    d1=((mg1[i]-mg1[i-1])**2)+(((p1[f]-p1[f-1])**2)**0.5)
    d2.append(d1)
d=np.array([d2])
```

Im not sure what the best approach would be, any help would be great thanks

p1=[0. 0.01816861 0.04215419 0.05918963 0.07256112 0.07437664 0.08547934 0.09885083 0.10157289 0.11222232 0.12604708 0.12831587 0.13941858 0.15279007 0.15600317 0.15827196 0.16616156 0.18274616 0.20805622 0.20994241 0.21228187 0.22565337 0.23902486 0.25284962 0.26576784 0.27913933 0.2929641 0.30633559 0.31813677 0.31970708 0.33150826 0.34093527 0.34487976 0.35430676 0.36767825 0.38150301 0.39487451 0.408246 0.42161749 0.43498898 0.43893347 0.44881374 0.45275823 0.46612972 0.47231072 0.47995449 0.48658875 0.49077907 0.49332598 0.49950697 0.50460384 0.50669747 0.51333174 0.51797533 0.52052223 0.52670323 0.53134682 0.53302252 0.54007472 0.54471831 0.54684728 0.55344621 0.56021877 0.58252866 0.59590015 0.60972491 0.61049407 0.62309641 0.6364679 0.64732477 0.65033043 0.66164057 0.66370193 0.67364982 0.67707342 0.69044491 0.70426967 0.7063633 0.71809443 0.72064134 0.7229808 0.7319192 0.73541041 0.73963607 0.74529069 0.74968845 0.75915322 0.76222407 0.7732561 0.77559556 0.78942033 0.79601926 0.80233855 0.80939075 0.82276224 0.8295348 0.836587 0.85627779 0.87055825 0.88347404 0.91021702 0.91988924 0.93745105 0.96967349]

mg1=[19.913 19.914 19.898 19.88 19.86 19.799 19.785 19.776 19.731 19.732 19.689 19.673 19.67 19.659 19.632 19.592 19.598 19.581 19.565 19.573 19.562 19.581 19.553 19.581 19.599 19.617 19.658 19.673 19.754 19.705 19.792 19.745 19.841 19.82 19.834 19.878 19.911 19.909 19.942 19.922 19.961 19.942 19.965 19.933 19.931 19.915 19.955 19.888 19.893 19.864 19.888 19.849 19.852 19.872 19.855 19.833 19.829 19.835 19.801 19.824 19.798 19.766 19.771 19.731 19.679 19.654 19.628 19.614 19.626 19.574 19.615 19.565 19.54 19.537 19.61 19.505 19.506 19.548 19.567 19.569 19.544 19.569 19.583 19.536 19.557 19.566 19.583 19.603 19.625 19.613 19.634 19.643 19.661 19.687 19.708 19.758 19.753 19.836 19.891 19.909 19.939 19.928 19.969 19.951]

Comment: show the full stacktrace and error message

Comment: How can we possibly help you?  We don't know what `p1` and `mg1` are.  Clearly, one of those contains something that isn't a valid index.  And are you sure you want your array to contain `[d2]` (a list within a list)?  Or did you just want `np.array(d2)`?

Comment: In this loop `f` and `i` will contain the data from `p1` and `mg1` themselves, not the indexes. You are probably looking for `for i in range(1,len(p1)):` instead and use only index `i` in the loop body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the way you are doing your for loop. Your `i` are values inside `mg1`, not the index. If you want to have access to the index (`i`) use the
`enumerate` function. Else, just use the values in `f,i` as they are (but you seem to need the index).

Problem, i is not an integer index, or a valid slice, but an element of mg1:

```
for f,i in zip(p1, mg1):
    d1=((mg1[i]-mg1[i-1])**2)+(((p1[f]-p1[f-1])**2)**0.5)
```

Solution:

```
import numpy as np
d = np.ones_like(p1)
for i, (p, m) in enumerate(zip(p1, mg1)):
    d[i]=((m-mg1[i-1])**2)+(((p-p1[i-1])**2)**0.5)
```

d is now a numpy array with the desired output. We also don't use lists so it's faster if the arrays are much bigger in reality.

This is not the only way to do it. But it's a simple way. `enumerate` is a useful helper function. You could also use only the index by using `range` as mentioned by Alex.

Option 2 using `range`:

```
d = np.ones_like(p1)
for i in range(len(p1)):
    d[i]=((mg1[i]-mg1[i-1])**2)+(((p1[i]-p1[i-1])**2)**0.5)
```

**Edit:** However, you should be careful about what you are actually trying to do. Because currently, the first iteration of the loop subtracts the last element of mg1 from the first element, as we are taking the i-1 element, which is -1, which in python is a reference to the last element. If you mean to subtract the first element from 0 instead, or skip the first element when subtracting, you should do things a bit differently instead. Here is a much more performant solution assuming you want to skip the first element.

**vectorized** performant solution assuming we skip the first element from subtraction. Modify appropriately to pad with zero or the last element instead.

```
mg1 = np.array(mg1)
p1 = np.array(p1)
d = np.sqrt((mg1[1:] - mg1[:-1])**2 + (p1[1:] - p1[:-1])**2)
```

As you see, we avoid looping and this implementation will be an order of magnitude faster which might matter if the arrays are large or this calculation is done thousands of times in your program. Testing in my Jupyter notebook, it's about 6x faster for these small arrays (19.2 microseconds vs 119 microseconds).

Comment: `for i,pm in enumerate(zip(p1, mg1)):` should probably just be `for i, (p, m) in enumerate(zip(p1, mg1)):`

Comment: @MadPhysicist Edited the answer, good catch., thanks Although I think the best answer is the vectorized version without unnecessary python looping, assuming the questioner knows what they want.

Comment: Agreed. By the way, it's bad form to use things like "edit" and "update" in your posts (as a general rule). An answer (or question) ought to represent the best you can come up with. Prior, incorrect or incomplete versions are not that, so you should not bring attention to them. If someone wants to see your edit history, thy can click on the appropriate link and look at it. It's a common misconception among beginners that your writing progress or prior work is somehow valuable to others. It's really more of an annoyance and distraction than anything.

Comment: I’ll change that. Thanks. I wasn’t sure about whether edits were discouraged or not. Some places discourage large edits.

Comment: Emir. SO encourages anything that improves the state of the art, large or small.